How to do a javascript fetch without being blocked by CORS policy?
I tried to run this javascript code on a Tampermonkey userscript on many webpages but they all gave the same problem: (I modified some details)
var data="744483"; var url="https://example.com/test.php?data="+data; fetch(url).then(response => response.text()) .then((response) => {alert(response);})
but it gave this problem:
Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/test.php?data=744483' from origin 'https://www.paxful.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
I tried this code but even though the code ran, no response was given back:
var data="744483"; var url="https://example.com/test.php?data="+data; fetch(url, { mode: 'no-cors'}).then(response => response.text()) .then((response) => {alert(response);})

You can't, the browser will obey the CORS instructions it receives from the server (unlike tools like curl or wget). Unless the server you're talking to allows you to access the URLs you want, nothing you do will let you bypass that security model in the browser (unless you start that browser up with security disabled, which should be an obvious non-solution). Of course, if you're trying to talk to your own server, then simply configure it so that it sends appropriate CORS headers that lets you use your own data.

FYI mode: "no-cors" is guaranteed not to return data - see documentation -

The server you are requesting (example.com) must have a CORS rule to allow requests coming from your server (paxful.com). This is done by the server administrators, so you can't do anything to solve the issue unless they allow your server to make requests to their server and get back responses.
